# Userdir not working as expected

Tags: drombler-fx

still following the Getting Started version 0.9.

When I run the sample application using the `java -Duser.language...` command I'm expecting to find the cache folder inside `test-application/target/userdir`. Instead it is inside `test-application/target/userdir/target/userdir`. Is it the correct behaviour?

When I run the sample application using the `java -Duser.language...` command **without** the `--userdir target/userdir` option, the following directory is created inside `test-application':`{user.home}/.foo/1.0.0-SNAPSHOT/{user.home}/.foo/1.0.0-SNAPSHOT`. Inside it the cache folder can be found. Is it the correct behaviour?

When I run the application double-clicking `foo.jar`, inside `test-application/target/deployment/standalone/bin` the following directory is created: `{user.home}/.foo/1.0.0-SNAPSHOT/{user.home}/.foo/1.0.0-SNAPSHOT`. Inside it the cache folder can be found. Is it the correct behaviour?

Thank you in advance for your help.
Claudio

Comment: Same configuration (OS, Java version, Maven version) as used in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42669251/running-the-sample-application-using-mvn-execexec-doesnt-work ?

Comment: yes, same configuration

Answer (score 0):

This is an issue in v0.9

Please note that with "mvn exec:exec" the userdir gets created correctly.

Please file the issue [here](https://github.com/Drombler/drombler-fx/issues).

Comment: This issue has been fixed with v0.10, which is now available: http://puces-blog.blogspot.ch/2017/07/drombler-fx-version-010-released.html